# Sort list model with priority id's and date time

Tags: android, sorting, arraylist, collections, quicksort

Sample List

```
ArrayList<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

list.add(new MyObject (1, "2011-04-27T09:40:01.607")); 
list.add(new MyObject (1, "2011-05-27T09:42:01.607"));
list.add(new MyObject (2, "2011-06-27T09:42:01.607"));
list.add(new MyObject (5, "2011-07-27T09:43:01.607"));
list.add(new MyObject (6, "2011-08-27T09:44:01.607"));
list.add(new MyObject (6, "2011-09-27T09:45:01.607"));
list.add(new MyObject (1, "2011-10-27T09:46:01.607"));
```

1:-How to Sort ArrayList with the respect of Id's

Required Output

```
list.get(0)= (1, "2011-04-27T09:40:01.607")); 
list.get(1)=(1, "2011-05-27T09:42:01.607"));
list.get(2)= (1, "2011-10-27T09:46:01.607"));
list.get(3)=(2, "2011-06-27T09:42:01.607"));
list.get(4)=(5, "2011-07-27T09:43:01.607"));
list.get(5)=(6, "2011-08-27T09:44:01.607"));
list.get(6)=(6, "2011-09-27T09:45:01.607"));
```

2:-When id's are sorted then every group of id's sort according according to its date

Means id (1) exist 3 time so id (1) sort according to its date

Required output

```
list.get(0)= (1, "2011-10-27T09:46:01.607"));
list.get(1)=(1, "2011-05-27T09:46:01.607"));
list.get(2)= (1, "2011-04-27T09:46:01.607")); 
list.get(3)=(2, "2011-06-27T09:46:01.607"));
list.get(4)=(5, "2011-07-27T09:46:01.607"));
list.get(5)=(6, "2011-08-27T09:46:01.607"));
list.get(6)=(6, "2011-09-27T09:46:01.607"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have 2 comparators like following

`IdSorter.java`

```
public class IdSorter implements Comparator<MyObject> 
    {
        public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) 
        {
            return o1.getId() - o2.getId();
        }
    }
```

`DateSorter.java`

```
public class DateSorter implements Comparator<MyObject> 
    {
        public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) 
        {
            return o1.getTime().compareTo(o2.getTime());
        }
    }
```

Then you can sort like following

**Java 8**

```
Collections.sort(list, new IdSorter()
               .thenComparing(new DateSorter()));
```

**Below Java 8**

`MyObjectChainedComparator.java`

```
public class MyObjectChainedComparator implements Comparator<MyObject> {

    private List<Comparator<MyObject>> listComparators;

    @SafeVarargs
    public MyObjectChainedComparator(Comparator<MyObject>... comparators) {
        this.listComparators = Arrays.asList(comparators);
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
        for (Comparator<MyObject> comparator : listComparators) {
            int result = comparator.compare(o1, o2);
            if (result != 0) {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Use the class `MyObjectChainedComparator.java` like following

```
Collections.sort(list, new MyObjectChainedComparator(
               new IdSorter(),
               new DateSorter()));
```

Your result will look like this

```
Id 1 Time 2011-04-27T09:40:01.607
Id 1 Time 2011-05-27T09:42:01.607
Id 1 Time 2011-10-27T09:46:01.605
Id 2 Time 2011- 06-27T09:42:01.607
Id 5 Time 2011-07-27T09:43:01.607
Id 6 Time 2011-08-27T09:44:01.607
Id 6 Time 2011-09-27T09:45:01.607
```

Comment: @Swayangit 
.thenComparing is a built in function and what this function do?

Comment: It's same as SQL group by clause. This method returns a lexicographic-order comparator with another comparator.

Comment: ok now i will implement it, if any issue occur i will post in comment or accept the answer

Comment: Cool .  Good luck :)

Comment: @Swayangit thenComparing
required 24 api level my minimum api level is 16

Comment: thenComparing is not a an android API its a java-8 API

Comment: brother it shows message
call required api level 24 (current minimum 16) :Java.util.comparator

Comment: Updated the answer. Let me know if it's showing any error or not

Comment: Thanks works like charm
tell me one thing MyObjectChainedComparator is not run in Java 8?. because MyObjectChainedComparator  not show me any error.
may i use only MyObjectChainedComparator or both?

Comment: you can use MyObjectChainedComparator, IdSorter, DateSorter for below java 8.

Comment: ok
how this code works because it will not compare the date, but return the expected result?
for (Comparator<MyObject> comparator : listComparators) {
            int result = comparator.compare(o1, o2);
            if (result != 0) {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return 0;

Comment: JVM internally converts string to Date  and then compare it

Comment: ok
but I donot understand this logic how its work.

  for (Comparator<MyObject> comparator : listComparators) {
            int result = comparator.compare(o1, o2);
            if (result != 0) {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return 0;

Comment: @Swayangit is it possible to tell me some thing how it works

for (Comparator<MyObject> comparator : listComparators) { int result = comparator.compare(o1, o2); if (result != 0) { return result; } } return 0;

Comment: Complete description is available in this blog (https://www.journaldev.com/780/comparable-and-comparator-in-java-example)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to Solve this use this Logic also

```
Collections.sort(list, new MyObjectChainedComparator());
```

Make class

```
public class MyObjectChainedComparator implements Comparator<MyObject> {


@Override
public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
     int result=o1.getId()-o2.getId();
     if (result==0)
     result =o2.getDate().compareTo(o1.getDate());
     return result;


}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new class such as `SortList` and `implement` the `Comparator` interface as below:

```
class SortList implements Comparator<MyObject> {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
        if (o1.id < o2.id) {// less than
            return -1;
        } else if (o1.id > o2.id) {// greater than
            return 1;
        } else {// equal
            // If it is equal then compare by name
            return o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);
        }
    }
}
```

And then, sorting the list like this

```
public void sort() {
    ArrayList<MyObject> list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(new MyObject(1, "abcd"));
    list.add(new MyObject(1, "a"));
    list.add(new MyObject(1, "abc"));
    list.add(new MyObject(1, "ab"));

    Collections.sort(list, new SortList());

    for (MyObject o : list) {
        System.out.println("id: " + o.id + ", name: " + o.name);
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
id: 1, name: a
id: 1, name: ab
id: 1, name: abc
id: 1, name: abcd
```

Note that: you have to change my code to compare the `Date` instead of `String`. I just wrote a simple example to let you understand how it works.

Comment: But this algo not sort according to the datetime

Comment: Try to parse the date string to `java.util.Date` object before sorting

Comment: i need when id's are sorted then want (every group of id's) sort by datetime

Comment: how it parse the object?

Comment: Replace `return o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);` to `return date1.compareTo(date2);`

Comment: Have a look this one; https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-to-date