# How to sort a Arraylist with Strings and a Double?

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist

I'm a Java beginner and I want to sort a Arraylist with entries of some Strings (location, description, ...) and one Double (the Distance to my local Point) from lowest distance to farest distance. Would be fine, if someone could help me. I experimentet with comperator, but didn*t get it to work for me.

```
final List<Entries> alleEintraege = response.body();
 // Arraylist is filled with Strings only because of getting entries from JSON

 // Distance to actual Point (part1)
 Location locationA = new Location("");
 locationA.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(myActuelLatitude));
 locationA.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(myActuelLongitude));

 listView = findViewById(R.id.list_view);

 // Alte Liste aus Json in for-Schleife durchlaufen
 for (Entries einzeleintrag : alleEintraege) {

     // Distance to actual Point (part2)
     Location locationB = new Location("");
     locationB.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(einzeleintrag.getLatitude()));
     locationB.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(einzeleintrag.getLongitude()));

     // Distance to actual Point (part3)
     double distance = round((locationA.distanceTo(locationB))/1000,1);

     // Hier die Distanz in jedes Entry-Objekt setzen
     einzeleintrag.setMyDistance(distance);
 } // End for-Schleife

 // Now I have filled my Arraylist with entries of some Strings and one Double (local Point) and I want to sort them from lowest distance to farest distance
```

Comment: Have a look on my old answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58776734/sort-list-model-with-priority-ids-and-date-time/58776916#58776916

Comment: show what you tried with the comparator

Comment: @John Le: Thanks very much! With your Description I got it to work now as a charm. So thanks alot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort list model with priority id's and date time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58776734/sort-list-model-with-priority-ids-and-date-time)